# Command line keeps saying that fileX :is a directory"

Tags: git, github, command-line, terminal, github-enterprise

I've currently been working on this website for the past few weeks. I want to add the project to my school's Github Enterprise, but keep encountering the following problem (link below is a screen recording):

https://streamable.com/2j4t37

I keep trying to drag the desired folder (titled 'Web-development') so that I can initialize the git repository but it keeps saying that "Web-development: is a directory". What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I created a repository for my web development class last semester, so I don't know if I created a repository for my whole disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you drag an item (file/directory) from the Finder to the Terminal window, the item’s absolute path will appear on the command line. If you want to navigate to the Web-development directory shown in the video, issue cd terminal, then drag the directory Web-development from the Finder to the Terminal window, and then hit enter. Then you can proceed with initializing your Git repository. Or, if you want to directly open the terminal window from the Web-development directory, do right click on Web-development directory from Finder -> Services -> New Terminal at Folder.

You can follow [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) steps to add your existing project to GitHub using the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing that and thought I got somewhere. I've completely confused myself at this point. What would be the steps for someone starting from scratch? I'll delete the repository and just try again.

Comment: You can checkout this link: https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line